# Show injectivity of two functions - check my proof

Tags: functions, inverse-function

While reading the proof of the inverse function theorem I stumbled on the following and I am not sure if I have comprehended the idea correctly.

*Let be $g$ a function $g: V \to U$, where $U:= g(V)$ and be $f$ another function with $f: U \to V.$ Further we assume that $(f\circ g)(x)=x.$*

Now I want to show that both functions are injective and that $f$ is the inverse of $g$:

1.) We take two $x,y \in V$ with $g(x)=g(y).$ It follows that $f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) \Rightarrow x=y.$ Hence, $g$ is injective.

2.) Now we take $m,n \in U$ with $f(m)=f(n)$. Then there exist two $x,y \in V$ with $g(x)=m$ and $g(y)=n.$ From $f(m)=f(n)$ it follows that $f(g(x))=f(g(y)).$ As we know that $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ we can conclude: $x=y \Rightarrow g(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow m=n.$

3.) Let be $y \in U$ so we now that there exists a $x \in V$ with $g(x) =y.$ Hence, $(g \circ f)(y) = g(f(y))=g(x)=y \Rightarrow g \circ f = y$

Are these steps proven correctly?

Comment: 1 and 3 look right to me, there are some confusingly placed parentheses in part 2 though, like in $f(g(x)=m)$.

Comment: Ah okay I edited the question.

Comment: Looks good to me. You are skipping a few small details, such as why $f(m)=f(n)$ implies $x=y$, but those are not necessarily needed.

Comment: I added the reason for this implication.